# Returning the contents of a HTML div with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have a directory of similar structured HTML files (two examples given):

File-1.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="bar"><div><p>bar</p></div></div>
        <div class="baz">baz</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

File-2.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="bar"><div><p>apple<br>banana</p></div></div>
        <div class="baz">baz</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a Powershell script to return the contents of the `bar` div, stripped from all html:

For File-1.html: `bar`
For File-2.html: `apple banana`

I now have:

```
$directory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sandbox\HTML"

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem($directory))
{
    $content = Get-Content "$directory\$file"

    echo $content.ParsedHtml.getElementById("bar").innerHTML
}
```

This returns an error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sandbox\parse-html.ps1:9 char:2 
+     echo $content.ParsedHtml.getElementById("bar").innerHTML`
```

I don't understand this error, as `bar` is an HTML element that exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does $content have a value? The error tells You that the variable You are calling a method on Is null

Comment: Yes, when I do an `echo $content`, the HTML for File-1.html is returned.

Comment: ok what about $content.ParsedHtml?

Comment: That value is null. I don't understand why.

Comment: because $content does not have a property called ParsedHtml, powershell does not support parsing html files by default i think. you can try using http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/.
Or you could just treat the line as the string it is and try to get the content of the tag with a REGEX

Comment: Some help with my regex please? I'm new to regex and what I have now does not return anything: `$test = [regex]::matches($content, '(?<=<div class="bar">\s+)(.*?)</div>')` I think I was doing rather well :-)

Comment: Haha :) Sorry i´m not a regex guru myself :) The only tip i can give you is to try regex101.com, it shows syntax errors and stuff. also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306596/regex-to-extract-the-contents-of-a-div-tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 $content = Get-Content File-1.html
 $xmlContent = [xml]$content

 $bar = $xmlContent.html.body.div | where {$_.div -eq 'bar'}

 Write-Output $bar.InnerXML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$text = Get-Content File-1.html
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($text)
$bar = $html.body.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0]
$bar.innerText
```